# How to convert a dataframe to a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, reshape

I want to transfer a named vector to matrix and fill up missing values (fill with 0s).

For example, I have a dataframe like this:

```
col1     col2    col3
Cancer1  Gene1   2.1
Cancer1  Gene2   2.51
Cancer1  Gene3   3.0
Cancer2  Gene1   0.9
```

Which has two columns of names: `col1` and `col2`. Then I want to transform this into a matrix, like:

```
        Cancer1   Cancer2
Gene1   2.1       0.9
Gene2   2.51      0
Gene3   3.0       0
```

If there are missing values in the vector, fill with 0s.

How can I do this efficiently in R?

Comment: It looks to me you want to convert a data.frame into a matrix...

Comment: Yes. It is a data.frame, but only with one column of values. Others are names.

Comment: `tidyr::spread(mydata, col1, col3)`

Comment: You want `xtabs(col3 ~ col1 +clo2, data=your.data.frame.name)`. This will return a table object which inherits methods from the matrix class.

Comment: @42-  `xtabs(col3 ~ col2 +col1, data=your.data.frame.name)` will be exactly what OP wants. (genes in the rows and cancers in the columns)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `tidyr` package:

```
tidyr::spread(mydata, col1, col3, fill = 0)

#    col2 Cancer1 Cancer2 
# 1 Gene1    2.10     0.9 
# 2 Gene2    2.51     0.0 
# 3 Gene3    3.00     0.0
```

***Data:***

```
mydata <- structure(list(col1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Cancer1", 
"Cancer2"), class = "factor"), col2 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L), .Label = c("Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene3"), class = "factor"), 
col3 = c(2.1, 2.51, 3, 0.9)), .Names = c("col1", "col2", 
"col3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 3):

Either `xtabs` or `tapply` should do it.

```
tapply(my.df$col3, rev(my.df[-3]), c)
       col1
col2    cancer1 cancer2
  gene1     2.1     2.2
  gene2     2.5      NA
  gene3      NA     3.0
```

`tapply` would have the advantage that, if there were multiple instances of any one combination, you could return a function result like `mean` applied to the group.

```
xtabs(col3 ~ col2 +col1, my.df)  #same matrix result
```

Note that using `tidyverse` methods like `spread` are likely to give you data-objects of a  "special" class (not matrices), which if you're not expecting them may have annoying properties, or if you *are* expecting them may seem wonderful.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a nested sapply, looping through each gene and cancer type. Use levels if you have factors or unique() if you have a character vector.

```
my.df <- data.frame(col1=c("cancer1", "cancer1", "cancer2", "cancer2"),
           col2=c("gene1", "gene2", "gene3", "gene1"), 
           col3=c(2.1, 2.5, 3.0, 2.2))

my.mat <- sapply(levels(my.df$col1), (function(cancer){
  sapply(levels(my.df$col2), (function(gene){
    tmp <- my.df[my.df$col1 == cancer & my.df$col2 == gene, "col3"]
    if (length(tmp) > 0) {
      as.numeric(tmp[1])
    } else {
      NA
    }
  }))
}))
my.mat
```

Comment: `else {
      NA` should be `else {
      0`.

Comment: Much more complex than it should be.

Comment: @Masoud: About `else { NA`... You are right... But only if you assume that the gene expression level is missing because it wasn't expressed at all just in a selected sample...

Comment: @DamianoFantini *"If there are missing values in the vector, fill with 0s."* OP explicitly wants zeros.

Comment: I know what was stated in the request, and I told you were right... I was just suggesting to be careful with such biological assumptions while working with gene expression data. That's all.

Comment: Agree. Missing is missing/ not zero.